# Unreal Engine 5.1.1: Key Press Event Not Triggering in Empty Level with Custom Player

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am learning Unreal Engine 5.1.1. and I have tried to integrate the [Photorealistic 3D Tiles from the Google Maps Platform in Cesium for Unreal](https://cesium.com/learn/unreal/unreal-photorealistic-3d-tiles/).

I am able to successfully integrate Google Maps with cesium into unreal projects.

And further, I created a BluePrint, called `BP_Player`.

By these steps,

[image: Globe aware default pawn]

And I got the Blueprint with this name.

[image]

and then after I created the following event graph,

[image]

and added an event with the R key pressed to print the text `Hello` in the screen.

and I run the application, and Press `R`, nothing happens on the screen.

and I checked the BP the event hasn't been activated.

Additionally, I added a Print String node to the beginning of the event graph and connected it to the Exec output of the Event Begin Play node.

[image]

This prints a string to the console window when the game starts. If you see the printed string.

[image]

What else do I need to set up to make this work? Most of the tutorials start with the starter content, and everything seems working, but when I start with the empty level. I am not able to work, what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you possessing the actor on start? If not, try possessing the actor manually then testing the key input.